# Calling manually getLastKnownLocation with service

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

I want to get current location of user by specific time interval (for instance get it every 30 seconds) to do that I wrote a service which manage this calling operation. Calling getLastKnownLocation by specific time interval is ok,  but every time it gives me same location info. I ran the app and started to drive with the car but nothing changed.

If I implement LocationListener and use onLocationChanged, this time the specific time interval does not work even if I set the location manager as below.

```
_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, (1 * 20 * 1000), 1, this); // recall in every 20 seconds or distance between 200 meters
```

Why I am getting always same location even If I change my location?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't set any criterias or got a bad provider. Have you remembered to set the necessary permissions in the manifest?

You can use this to request location updates:

```
// Get best providers and set criteria
LocationManager lm;
Criteria crit = new Criteria();
crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
String towers = lm.getBestProvider(crit, false);

// Set provider and update interval
lm.requestLocationUpdates(towers, 5000, 20, this); // minimum 5 seconds, 20 meters
```

Remember that the time interval set in the requestLocationUpdates is minimum, and not accurate.

To get the last known location:

```
LocationManager locationManager = ((LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE));
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

To get the longitude and latitude:

```
location.getLatitude();
location.getLongitude();
```

This works for me.

Comment: Actually I just want to know that how getLastKnownLocation works? Why it gives me the same location info again and again?

Comment: @MustafaGüven: As far as I have understood, getLastKnownLocation is a completely passive method that just returns the last location fix the phone has. So, if any application retrieves the current location of the device, you will get that from getLastKnownLocation. BUT if no one has retrieved any location, it returns NULL or even a very, very old location.